# PSpice: sinusoidal voltage

Tags: spice, pspice

I should get i(t) on PSpice.

[image]

I tried doing it by writing the following code:

```
VIN 1 0 SIN(0 2 18.8495 0 0 60)
R1 1 2 2
C1 2 3 0.33
L1 3 0 1
R2 3 4 2
C2 4 0 0.166
VP 4 0 0
.OP
.END
```

The output is:

```
NODE   VOLTAGE     NODE   VOLTAGE     NODE   VOLTAGE     NODE   VOLTAGE


(    1)    0.0000  (    2)    0.0000  (    3)    0.0000  (    4)    0.0000  




    VOLTAGE SOURCE CURRENTS
    NAME         CURRENT

    VIN          0.000E+00
    VP           0.000E+00

    TOTAL POWER DISSIPATION   0.00E+00  WATTS
```

All voltages are 0s, and I think it should not be.

Thanks

EDIT:
I tried this, using phasors. I calculated 0.47A for i(t), but I get 1.000E-30 on spice

```
VS 1 0 AC 2 60
R1 1 2 2
C1 2 3 0.33
L1 3 0 1
R2 3 4 2
C2 4 0 0.166

.AC LIN 1 18 18
.PRINT AC I(C2) IP(C2)
```

Comment: .OP calculates the DC operating point, given the DC source values. What DC voltage did you specify for your source? Hint: the 'SIN' part is a transient voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks, I used phasors at this time (check the question)

Comment: Hint: Include VP in your schematic and you should see the problem.

Comment: @ThePhoton I get the same result also removing that element

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file before running the simulator. Also remember your schematic shows 3 rad/s operating frequency but you simulate at 1 and 18 Hz (but this is not your main problem). You could also just have a PSpice syntax problem and I wouldn't be able to see it because I don't use PSpice.

Comment: Oh, and the step between 1 and 18 Hz is not 18 Hz.

Comment: Just noticing: by the look of the first code, I see you placed `Vp` in *parallel* with the capacitor, not in *series* (voltage sources have zero internal resistance, thus shunting `C2`). The second code looks good. @ThePhoton I think the `.AC` command is over one point (from 18Hz to 18Hz).